# Filtering file in unix using grep/sed/awk other?

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I have gigantic error log files that show errors encountered on a dataload.

I need to report errors that are NOT unique constrain violations, but searching through the files manually are impractical due to their size.

The log file:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table DMT_.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DM.DMT__PK) violated

Record 2: Rejected - Error on table DMT_.
ORA-01400:cannot insert NULL in to("DM"."DMT_INSURANCE"."INSURANCE_FUND_CODE")

Record 3: Rejected - Error on table DMT_.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (DM.DMT__PK) violated

Record 4: Rejected - Error on table DMT_ADDRESS, column ORIGINAL_POSTCODE.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "DM"."DMT_ADDRESS"."ORIGINAL_POSTCODE" (actual: 12, maximum: 10)
```

Desired output file is

```
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table DMT_.
ORA-01400:cannot insert NULL in to("DM"."DMT_INSURANCE"."INSURANCE_FUND_CODE")

Record 4: Rejected - Error on table DMT_ADDRESS, column ORIGINAL_POSTCODE.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "DM"."DMT_ADDRESS"."ORIGINAL_POSTCODE" (actual: 12, maximum: 10)
```

I'm pretty sure this can be done in grep, sed or awk, but I'm new to this sort of thing...I'd really appreciate a pointer or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using Perl-regex (with negative lookahead) to exclude the ORA-00001 and then get the line before the matching ORAs too (-B1):

```
grep -B1 -P 'ORA\-(?!00001)' logfile
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks to you and all!

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep`.  You *don't* want the lines that would be produced by:

```
grep -B1 "unique constraint.*violated" filename
```

Now *eliminate* these lines from the input:

```
grep -v -f <(grep -B1 "unique constraint.*violated" filename) filename
```

and you get the result:

```
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table DMT_.
ORA-01400:cannot insert NULL in to("DM"."DMT_INSURANCE"."INSURANCE_FUND_CODE")


Record 4: Rejected - Error on table DMT_ADDRESS, column ORIGINAL_POSTCODE.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "DM"."DMT_ADDRESS"."ORIGINAL_POSTCODE" (actual: 12, maximum: 10
```

(This *assumes* that the `Record ...` and `ORA-...` are on different lines.  If those are on the same line, `grep -v "unique constraint.*violated" filename` would work!)

Answer (score 2):

If you have `perl` available you can use its paragraph mode:

```
$ perl -00 -ne 'print unless /unique constraint/m;' < foo.input
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table DMT_.
ORA-01400:cannot insert NULL in to("DM"."DMT_INSURANCE"."INSURANCE_FUND_CODE")

Record 4: Rejected - Error on table DMT_ADDRESS, column ORIGINAL_POSTCODE.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "DM"."DMT_ADDRESS"."ORIGINAL_POSTCODE" (actual: 12, maximum: 10)
```

Same using `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS= '!/unique constraint/' foo.input
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table DMT_.
ORA-01400:cannot insert NULL in to("DM"."DMT_INSURANCE"."INSURANCE_FUND_CODE")
Record 4: Rejected - Error on table DMT_ADDRESS, column ORIGINAL_POSTCODE.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "DM"."DMT_ADDRESS"."ORIGINAL_POSTCODE" (actual: 12, maximum: 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Record/{N;N;/\nORA-00001:/d}' logfile
```

Read 3 lines for each record and if those lines contain the undesired code delete them.

If more filtering is needed, further codes may be added before the enclosing `}`.

Answer (score 1):

One way using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). For every field that begins with `Record` read next one and try to match the string `unique ...`. If it doesn't suceed, print both adding a newline.

```
sed -n '/^Record/ { N; /unique constraint .* violated/! { s/$/\n/; p } }' infile
```

It yields:

```
Record 2: Rejected - Error on table DMT_.
ORA-01400:cannot insert NULL in to("DM"."DMT_INSURANCE"."INSURANCE_FUND_CODE")

Record 4: Rejected - Error on table DMT_ADDRESS, column ORIGINAL_POSTCODE.
ORA-12899: value too large for column "DM"."DMT_ADDRESS"."ORIGINAL_POSTCODE" (actual: 12, maximum: 10)
```